# how to assign a new element in array.array

Tags: python

When I try to assign the array from array.array module as follows:

```
a = array('f')

a[0] = 2.2
```

I get array assignment out of range, so basically I have to allocate some dummy values and size in the first statement itself like `a = array('f',[0]*20)`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens with `list` also:

```
>>> L = []
>>> L[0] = 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Basically the `[]` syntax **requires** that the index is valid. It cannot be used to add elements.

The `array.array` class support most `list` methods, you can use those to add elements after creation.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily- you can also add elements using `append`:

```
a.append(2)
print a
# array('f', [2.0])
```

or `extend`:

```
a.extend([1, 2, 3, 4])
print a
# array('f', [2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
```

It thus works in much the same way as a regular Python list.